# Show that when $A$ is invertible, its inverse is $A^{-1} = I + αuv^T$ by finding $α$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $u$ and $v$ be $2$ non-zero (column) vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $A = I - uv^T$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.
> Show that when $A$ is invertible, its inverse is $A^{-1} = I + αuv^T$ by finding $α$.

I have previously found the eigenvalues of $A$, which are $\lambda_1 = 1$, and $\lambda_2 = 1-v^Tu$.
But I don't know if this would be of any help in finding the inverse as well as $\alpha$. Any help please?

Comment: Hint: What does the matrix product $(I-uv^T)(I+\alpha uv^T)$ equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
I&=A^{-1}A=(I+\alpha uv^T)(I-uv^T)\\
&=I-uv^T+\alpha uv^T-\alpha uv^Tuv^T\\
&=I+(\alpha-1-\alpha v^Tu)uv^T.
\end{align*}

Note that $$uv^Tuv^T=u(v^Tu)v^T=u\cdot \text{scalar}\cdot v^T=\text{scalar}\cdot uv^T=(v^Tu)\cdot uv^T$$

Hence, we have to consider $\alpha-1-\alpha v^Tu=0\implies \alpha=\frac{1}{1-v^Tu}.$

Comment: How do we know uv_T is non-zero?